Expected type 'object'. Found 'array<string, mixed>'. (Intelephense 1006). Can anyone help me please?
My Laravel code works fine but the PHP Intelephense extension shows unnecessary error in the code. If I delete the extension, the error goes away and reappears when I reinstall it. It also shows some errors in the Laravel helpers.php folder too. My tutor uses PHPStorm and he calls the request() directly doesn’t get any errors. I mean I use VSCode and the request() works without any error but I just want to fix the squiggly error. Can anyone help me fix this issue?

I tried uninstalling and tried again but the error doesn’t go away. Also tried configuring the settings.json file with help of chatGPT but didn’t work out either. :(

Not sure my answer will solve your issue. What version of Laravel are you using? Can you post the helpers.php file around the line 223 ? event() is undefined seems to be your primary issue.

I’m using Laravel 11.14. I’ve included the link of the screenshot. link

This question is similar to: Undefined functions/methods - Intelephense(1013) - Laravel Homestead + VScode. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. The code + squiggly error can probably be included as text in an [edit].

I came across a PHP Intelephense dev on github, he told me that it was an error in the PHP Intelephense extension and said that they've fixed it in the latest release. After updating the extension, it did fix the issue.
//But there are few more errors still in the helpers and other folders but he said they'll fix it soon.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

In order for VS code to find the request function, it relies on the vendor/laravel/framework/composer.json file. Specificially the definition inside this block referring to the Foundation/helpers.php file.
 "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "src/Illuminate/Collections/helpers.php",
            "src/Illuminate/Events/functions.php",
            "src/Illuminate/Filesystem/functions.php",
            "src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php",
            "src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Illuminate\\": "src/Illuminate/",
            "Illuminate\\Support\\": [
                "src/Illuminate/Macroable/",
                "src/Illuminate/Collections/",
                "src/Illuminate/Conditionable/"
            ]
        }
    },

Make sure this definition exists. if not, you can always add it to your own composer.json file.

Thank you but I do have these definitions in the composer.json file tho. :(

The problem here is the docblock in the request(). Almost all helpers have this problem. I think it is because of these change [11.x] feat: add more specific types and tests for helpers
Edit #1
If it really bothers you you can put a null value inside the request()
request(null)->validate(...);

